# Clear Print Range in Pyuno?

Tags: python, uno, pyuno

I'm using unoconv to convert some xlsx spreadsheets to pdf, and need to clear the print area that's been set in the xlsx, as the pdf only contains those cells in the print area.  Looking through the OO docs would suggest that I need to set the RenderOptions.PrintRange attribute to "".  Does anyone know how to reference the RenderOptions object via Pyuno?